# Subtraction in SQL Server up to 3 decimal places

Tags: sql-server

I have table `P` in a SQL Server database.

In table `P`, I have a value 234.6 in column A and 234.595 in column B.

A query

```
select A-B 
from P
```

yields the result

```
0.004999999999545
```

It ideally should be

```
0.005
```

What should I do to get result as 0.005?

Comment: What are the data types?

Comment: This is usually something handled in your presentation layer.

Comment: casting to decimal is a solution for you? `select cast(a as decimal(6,3))-cast(b as decimal(6,3)) from P` -> 0.005

Comment: Use `ROUND`. [ROUND (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/round-transact-sql)

Answer (score 1):

If your data types are not appropriate, you can get rounding anomalies

Consider these 3 queries

```
select cast(234.6 as decimal(12,6)) - cast(234.595 as decimal(12,6))
select cast(234.6 as decimal(12,3)) - cast(234.595 as decimal(12,3))
select cast(234.6 as float) - cast(234.595 as float)
```

The results are:

```
0.005000
0.005
0.00499999999999545
```

`Cast` your columns as required